# Retrieve value of a textarea with PHP

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Would anyone perhaps know how to get the value of a specific element in an HTML document with PHP? What I'm doing right now is using `file_get_contents` to pull up the HTML code from another website, and on that website there is a textarea:

```
<textarea id="body" name="body" rows="12" cols="75" tabindex="1">Hello World!</textarea>
```

What I want to do is have my script do the `file_get_contents` and just pull out the "Hello World!" from the textarea. Is that possible? Sorry for bugging you guys, again, you give such helpful advice :].

Comment: I'd suggest using a regular expression but would suspect I'd get shouted down for that =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't be sorry for bugging us, this is a good question I'm happy to answer. You can use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to get what you need:

```
$html     = file_get_html('http://www.domain.com/');
$textarea = $html->find('textarea[id=body]'); 
$contents = $textarea->innertext;

echo $contents; // Outputs 'Hello World!'
```

If you want to use `file_get_contents()`, you can do it like this:

```
$raw_html = file_get_contents('http://www.domain.com/');
$html     = str_get_html($raw_html);
...
```

Although I don't see any need for the `file_get_contents()` as you can use the `outertext` method to get the original, full HTML out if you need it somewhere:

```
$html     = file_get_html('http://www.domain.com/');
$raw_html = $html->outertext;
```

---

Just for the kicks, you can do this also with an one-liner regular expression:

```
preg_match('~<textarea id="body".*?>(.*?)</textarea>~', file_get_contents('http://www.domain.com/'), $matches);
echo $matches[1][0]; // Outputs 'Hello World!'
```

I'd strongly advise against this though as you are a lot more vulnerable to code changes which might break this regular expression.

Comment: I'm not getting any output, could it be the contents of the textbox? (they aren't blank)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using PHPs [DOM & DOMXPath](http://ar.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) classes.

```
$dom = DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile( $url );
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );
$nodes = $xpath->query('//textarea[id=body]' )

$result = array();
for( $nodes as $node ) {
    $result[] = $node->textContent;
}
```

There `$result` would contain the value of every textarea with id body.

Comment: So many good answers! Thank you all very much, you've been more than helpful.

Comment: When I use this code, I get an error: Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile() [domdocument.loadhtmlfile]: Unexpected end tag : input

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: That sounds like the HTML youre trying to parse is broken, a common nightmare. You should just go with Tatu's regexp solution.

Comment: Or throw [Tidy](http://us2.php.net/tidy) into the mix.  PCRE for Dom stuff is usually not the best solution.