# Return the value of a textarea in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am using Simple HTML DOM to scrap from a data form.  All I am interested in returning are inputs and textareas, names and values.  The names correspond to columns in a MySQL table.  It's mostly working as advertised except that I cannot get a return value on textareas.  I have searched on this site and others, and the closest I found to a solution was at [1]: [Retrieve value of a textarea with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307432/retrieve-value-of-a-textarea-with-php/2307451#2307451).

I found that I had to have two passes of "$html->load($result["body"])" to pick up the names and values of both inputs and textareas.  When I tried to include each in one pass the function picked up all of the inputs, but ignored the textareas.  So I added a second pass to pick up textareas, and it does return the textarea names, but none of the values.  I can see the values in both the page source and in the debugger.  In fact, any of defaultValue, innerHTML, textContent, and value all show the same output.  In place of "textarea[value]" I have tried all of the above mentioned attributes.  No errors, just nothing.

Here is a code snippet:

```
$url = "some url";
$web = new WebBrowser();
$result = $web->Process($url);

if (!$result["success"])  echo "Error retrieving URL.  " . $result["error"] . "\n";
else if ($result["response"]["code"] != 200)  echo "Error retrieving URL.  Server returned:  " . $result["response"]["code"] . " " . $result["response"]["meaning"] . "\n";
else
{
    echo "Order inputs: </br>";
    $html->load($result["body"]);
    $rows = $html->find("input[name]");
    $rows = $rows + $html->find("input[value]");
    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        echo "\t" . $row->name . "&nbsp;" . $row->value . "</br>";
    }
}

unset($html);
unset($result);
unset($rows);

$html = new simple_html_dom();
echo "</br></br>";

$result = $web->Process($url);

if (!$result["success"])  echo "Error retrieving URL.  " . $result["error"] . "\n";
else if ($result["response"]["code"] != 200)  echo "Error retrieving URL.  Server returned:  " . $result["response"]["code"] . " " . $result["response"]["meaning"] . "\n";
else
{
    echo "Order textarea(s): </br>";
    $html->load($result["body"]);
    $rows = $html->find("textarea[name]");
    $rows = $rows + $html->find("textarea[value]");
    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        echo "\t" . $row->name . "&nbsp;" . $row->value . "</br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that: "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object..."

Comment: So post what you tried. Obviously you wouldn't use _exactly_ what was in that answer, as it included a reference to an element class that you most likely aren't using.

Comment: ok.  in place of "textarea[value]",  substitute "textarea[innerHTML]" or "textarea[textContent]".  Didn't I already say that?  I did just now try "textarea[content]" and it returns content, text box and all.

Answer (score 1):

A textarea doesn't have a value. It has content (the stuff between the opening and closing tags), rather than a `value` attribute.

Comment: My debugger shows value, as well as the other attributes I mentioned.

Comment: Okay. You're welcome to keep using `value` then.. :~)

Comment: No, that is the point of the question.  Read again.  I tried the other attribututes and still get nothing.

Comment: That's because it is not an attribute at all. An input element has a value attribute: `<input value="Here it is!">`. A textarea has content: `<textarea>Here it is!</textarea>`.

Comment: I have the answer, but don't have enough points to answer my own question right now.  The answer is: plaintext, e.g.,
< $rows = $html->find("textarea[plaintext]"); >
Thanks guys, I know you tried.  And I apologize if I was snippy.

Comment: That should give you all textarea elements with a plaintext attribute. But simple will misunderstand that and give you all textareas. Either way it's not what you want.

Comment: No.  It is exactly what I want, and the return values are what I was looking for.  But thanks, anyway.

Comment: That's a 2 wrongs making a right kind of situation though. It's not a real solution.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, "plaintext"

```
$result = $web->Process($url);

if (!$result["success"])  echo "Error retrieving URL.  " . $result["error"] . "\n";
else if ($result["response"]["code"] != 200)  echo "Error retrieving URL.  Server returned:  " . $result["response"]["code"] . " " . $result["response"]["meaning"] . "\n";
else
{
    echo "Order textarea(s): </br>";
    $html->load($result["body"]);
    $rows = $html->find("textarea[name]");
    $rows = $rows + $html->find("textarea[plaintext]");

    $numtexts = 0;

    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        echo "\t" . $row->name . "&nbsp;" . $row->plaintext . "</br>";
        $numtexts = $numtexts + 1;
    }
}
```

This is a limited data form with predictable inputs and textareas.  As I said earlier, input and textarea names correspond to MySQL table columns, so it will be easy to map the returned values.  I found the answer that worked for me in the simple dom manual at Sourceforge.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want:

```
$html->find('textarea', 0)->text();
```

Comment: "Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in ..."